# Passing an image from Lambda to API Gateway

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambdas function that resizes and image, stores it back into S3. However I want to pass this image to my API to be returned to the client.

Is there a way to return a png image to the API gateway, and if so how can this be done?

Comment: API Gateway currently does not support binary responses, so it isn't possible. AWS has indicated that support for binary responses is on the road-map but it may be a long time before that is added.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway does not currently support passing through binary data either as part of a request nor as part of a response.  This feature request is on our backlog and is prioritized fairly high.

Answer (score 0):

You could return it base64-encoded...

Comment: Binary Data Now Supported by API Gateway
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/binary-data-now-supported-by-api-gateway/